# Importing modules for code that runs in the workers

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I wrote a simple job that filters an rdd using a custom function that uses a module.

Where is the correct place to put the import statement?

- putting the import in the driver code doesn't help
- putting the import inside the filter function works, but doesn't look very good

Answer (score 0):

You can submit jobs as batch operations with dependent modules using command line `spark-submit` interface. From the Spark 1.6.1 [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html), it has the following signature ...

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class <main-class>
  --master <master-url> \
  --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
  --conf <key>=<value> \
  ... # other options
  <application-jar> \
  [application-arguments]
```

If your python script is called `python_job.py` and the module upon which it depends is `other_module.py`, you'd call

```
 ./bin/spark-submit python_job.py --py-files other_module.py
```

This will make sure that other_module.py is on the worker nodes. It is more common that you'll submit a full package so you'd submit `other_module_library.egg` or even `.zip`. These should all be acceptable in `--py-files`.

If, however, you want to work in the interactive shell, I believe that you'll have to stick with importing the module within the function.

Comment: This handles the code distribution to the workers, but not the actual import